# Is there a #define in angular?

Tags: angular, angular9

Is there any way to achieve the #define functionality with Angular?

I'm talking about the ability to add/remove some code based on defines at compile time, just like C++,C# and other lower level programming languages do.

Comment: JavaScript is an interpreted language -- there is no "compile time".

Comment: Reason for reopening: I was not in agreement with the selected duplicate as it was specific to javascript. The question is about angular and I believe the OP is asking how to include specific code in the bundle based on a environment settings. This is possible as angular will generate a bundle and you can configure angular to execute a file replacement based on an environment which will have a functionally similar effect to using a preprocessor directives in c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible in the exact same manner as a preprocessor directive in c#. However, I assume you are wanting to do this at the time the js bundles are generated. What you can do is specify different *files* to include based on environment settings but there is not a way to omit only part of the code in the same file.

See the `angular.json` file and sections named `fileReplacements`. In the default `angular.json` file generated with `ng new` you can see that in the production environment (`ng build --prod`) the file `src/environments/environment.prod.ts` is included instead of `src/environments/environment.ts`. You can expand this to do additional replacements as needed.

```
"configurations": {
  "production": {
    "fileReplacements": [
      {
        "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
        "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

In angular this is the closest you can get to the equivalent of a preprocessor directive in c# AFAIK.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. File replacement is not an option for me, but knowing that there is no easy way of omitting/including parts of code i will most likely need to create some scripts that do the job before angular start building the bundle.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a plugin, you can use angular native optimization.

```
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
    console.log('@@@ environment.production @@@');
} else {
    console.log('@@@ NOT environment.production @@@');
}
```

when you run 'ng build --prod' only the statement within the first condition will be included in the bundle, without the if statement.

[Here the bundle screenshot, I highlighted the generated component code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctfGd.png)

Comment: can you post your answer here instead of puting a link ?

Comment: @phoenixstudio, I haven't used this package myself, but following your call I tried it so I can paste the code here.
I created a new project and followed the package docs, unfortunately this did not succeed.
I came to a conclusion that this package will not work for preprocessor. 
I guess there are 2 compilation stages: typescript (transpile to .js) and webpack, and this package works only after typescript, so it will not do preprocessing but only work on transpiled files.
so I was probably mistaken in my previous comment, sorry for that.
pity, it looks like there is no such preprocessor.

Comment: ok thanks for your hardwork, can you update your answer to match your findings ?

Comment: @phoenixstudio I have found a better solution and updated my answer.